# Does the angular momentum of a jet engine affect aircraft performance?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-physics, stability

I am interested, do jet engines have angular momentum? And how does such momentum affect airplane stability?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do turbine engines on multi-engine aircraft rotate in opposite directions to offset torque?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/700/do-turbine-engines-on-multi-engine-aircraft-rotate-in-opposite-directions-to-off)

Comment: Better to muse does any rapidly spinning object ever lack angular momentum?  Of course not.  The solution is to pair it with an identical oppositely rotating object or have some means of controlling its torque.  See helicopters and gyros to start.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question. The OP is clearly referring to angular momentum (not torque differential) and its effect on aircraft stability, which was not addressed in the other question.

Comment: Angular momentum becomes torque differential when the orientation of the spinning object is changed, much like a spinning bicycle wheel in your hand.  Some studies were done on the effect of the rotating (single) jet engine on the spin characteristics of an F-104, basicly making a complete mess of it due to gyroscopic effects.  Don't have enough hard info to post, but OP is on the right track.